# basic algebra question, regarding $\pm$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I know that $a_0,r^s \neq 0$ then

$$a_0[n^2\pi^2-\alpha^2s^2]r^s = 0$$

$$\implies s= \pm \frac{n\pi}{\alpha}$$

now on solving

$$a_1[n^2\pi^2-\alpha^2(s+1)^2]r^{s+1} = 0$$

we must have that $a_1 = 0$

since otherwise

$$1+s = \pm \frac{\pi n}{\alpha} \implies 1\pm\frac{\pi n}{\alpha} = \pm \frac{\pi n}{\alpha} \implies 1 = 0$$

Is this the correct reasoning? I have treated $\pm \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}  $as some constant $ K$

Comment: When you wrote "I know that $a_0, r^n \neq 0$", did you mean $r^s$ instead of $r^n$ by any chance?

Comment: yes i did! sorry I shall fix now

Comment: did you mean $\implies s = \pm \frac{n\pi}{\alpha}$? instead of $\implies s  \pm \frac{n\pi }{\alpha}$.  The latter is simply a number and not a statement.  It's like saying "Old macdonald had a farm $\implies$ pig"  well, what *about* pig?

Comment: also yes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take cases into account.

$s = \pm W \iff s = \{W|-W\}$

$1 + s = \pm W \iff 1 + s= \{W|-W\}$

So

$1 \pm W = \pm W \iff \{1 + W|1 - W\} = \{W|-W\}$

So $

$1 = \mp W \pm W \iff 1 = \{W+W|W-W|-W+W|-W-W\}$

$1 = \{0|2W|-2W\}$.

So $1 \ne 0$ this means $W = \pm 1/2$

So either $s = 1/2; 1+ 1/2 = \pm 1/2$ which is impossible.

Or $s = -1/2; 1 - 1/2 = 1/2$ which is possible so $W = \pm 1/2$ and $s = -|W|$.

Which can probably be shown to be impossible with one more step.

Comment: I thought I could not do as in my post above, just needed someone to confirm my suspicions! Thanks.

Comment: The extra step is that $W = \pm 1/2$ but $W$ is irrational by definition. I think.

Comment: Even if $W = \pm n$ we would still have a contradiction, since $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your reasoning is not correct. First of all I have the feeling you forgot an equal sign in your first equation, which should be
$$
s=\pm\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}.
$$

Now, let $a:=\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}$ to simplify notation.

Suppose $s=+a$, then you have two possibilities: $1+s=+a$ or $1+s=-a$.
The first case leads to $1+a=a$ which indeed yields the contradiction $1=0$, but the second case gives $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't imply any contradiction.

Same goes for the case where $s=-a$, which yields $1=0$ in one case, but $a=\frac{1}{2}$ in the other.